# C++11 'native_handle' is not a member of 'std::this_thread'

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

In the following code snippet,

```
void foo() {
  std::this_thread::native_handle().... //error here
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(foo);

  t1.join();
  return 0;
}
```

How do you get the `native_handle` from `std::this_thread` from within the function `foo`?

Comment: please also see my other answer to somewhat related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74832738/119609)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way for a thread to autonomously gain access to its own `std::thread`.  This is on purpose since `std::thread` is a move-only type.

I believe what you're requesting is a `native_handle()` member of `std::thread::id`, and that is an interesting suggestion.  As far as I know it is not currently possible.  It would be used like:

```
void foo()
{
    auto native_me = std::this_thread::get_id().native_handle();
    // ...
}
```

It wouldn't be guaranteed to work, or even exist.  However I imagine most POSIX platforms could support it.

One way to try to change the C++ standard is to submit issues.  [Here](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue) are directions on how to do so.

Comment: do you think something like this is worth submitting as a proposal for C++14?

Comment: @NicholasPezolano:  At this time no.  However I could be persuaded by a motivating use case and an implementation demonstrating it.  I.e. I think I know the cost/risk.  But I don't think I know the benefit.  If the benefit is zero, then no matter how low the cost, the benefit/cost ratio is poor.  So you would need to demonstrate a large benefit.

Comment: I don't think the OP necessarily wants `std::thread::id::native_handle`. I think the interesting point is: shouldn't the interface of `std::this_thread` mimic that of `std::thread`? Except of course for those members that relate to thread lifetime management, which as you rightfully point out doesn't make too much sense. That doesn't leave much, but `native_handle` strikes me as conspicuously absent.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I wanted to make a cross platform thread profiler/debugger,this would simplify things greatly, i'm sure that does not qualify as a large benefit however.

Comment: @NicholasPezolano:  It might, don't sell yourself short.  My point is that to sell something to the committee, it helps for them to see *why* something is needed.  It doesn't help nearly as much when you just say: why don't we do this.  I've personally never made a cross platform thread profiler/debugger.  So I'm clueless how this would simplify things greatly.  But I find myself wishing I knew.  A paper authored by yourself explaining things in more detail might motivate the committee.  Or it might not.  It is hard to predict the future.

Comment: Why not `std::this_thread::native_handle()`, just like it's with `get_id()`? This can be treated as "completion" - both things are available in all thread systems, both things do the same logically. If there's something wrong with `this_thread::native_handle()`, the same can be said about `std::thread::native_handle()`. You need motivating use case? Think about debugging. Gdb won't show you a list of thread with ID's returned by `this_thread::get_id()`.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74832738/119609

Answer (score 11):

C++11 does not provide a mechanism for getting the current threads native_handle. You must use platform specific calls, i.e. GetCurrentThread() on Windows:

```
void foo()
{
    auto native_me = ::GetCurrentThread();
}
```

Comment: Can't vote for my own post, but laughed out loud when I hit this problem again and came across this answer!

Answer (score 2):

As Howard pointed, there is no support for this in ISO C++ yet.

But `thread::id` has an overloaded [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/operator_ltlt) to **print** itself to an `ostream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}
```

Without knowing the semantics of the actual value (which is highly platform-dependent), printing it or using it as a key in a map is the most you should be doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Currently(C++17) you can't get `native_handle` from `std::this_thread`

The most possible interface might be `std::this_thread::native_handle()`. But not `std::this_thread::get_id().native_handle();` by [@Howard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16259324/4898526)

Since Win/Linux/MacOS implement `thread` and `thread::id` differently: (below is informal pseudo code)

- On Linux `native_handle` is stored at thread.**_M_id(of type id)**._M_thread.
- On Windows `native_handle` is stored at thread._Thr(of type _Thrd_t, not of type id)._Hnd.
- On MacOS `native_handle` is stored at thread.__t_.

As you can see only in Linux source there is `native_hanlde` object implemented in `thread::id` structure. Thus on Win/MacOS you can't get the `native_handle` from an `id` object.

Finally, if your code runs only in Linux, there is a dirty trick to get `native_handle` from `this_thread` which I will never recommend:

```
auto thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
auto native_handle = *reinterpret_cast<std::thread::native_handle_type*>(&thread_id);
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74832738/119609

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is one funny way to circumvent the problem and access it via std::thread , which may work in some cases.
The original example was posted on this [blog](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/). I rewritten it.
You can save the code below to test.cpp and compile & run it
:

```
// g++ ./test.cpp  -lpthread && ./a.out
// 
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  constexpr unsigned num_threads = 4;
  // A mutex ensures orderly access to std::cout from multiple threads.
  std::mutex iomutex;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
    threads[i] = std::thread([&iomutex, i,&threads] {
      // Create a cpu_set_t object representing a set of CPUs. Clear it and mark
      // only CPU i as set.
      cpu_set_t cpuset;
      CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
      CPU_SET(i, &cpuset);
      int rc = pthread_setaffinity_np(threads[i].native_handle(),
                                      sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
      if (rc != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error calling pthread_setaffinity_np: " << rc << "\n";
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
      while (1) {
        {
          // Use a lexical scope and lock_guard to safely lock the mutex only
          // for the duration of std::cout usage.
          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> iolock(iomutex);
          std::cout << "Thread #" << i << ": on CPU " << sched_getcpu() << "\n";
        }

        // Simulate important work done by the tread by sleeping for a bit...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(900));
      }
    });


  }

  for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
  }
  return 0;
}
```